Interpretation of coefficient for binomial longitudinal outcome in joint models / modeling
When performing joint models of survival and longitudinal outcome, how do we interpret the coefficient when the longitudinal outcome is binomial?
In the slides here pp. 131 to 142 https://www.drizopoulos.com/courses/EMC/ESP72.pdf
we can either consider the conditional expected value or conditional linear predictor (p. 133). With the conditional expected value we can use the vexpit function in JMbayes2
https://drizopoulos.github.io/JMbayes2/articles/Transformation_Functions.html
On page 139, we have the estimate of expit(value(spiders)) = 0.458. Here expit(value(spiders)) can take values between 0 and 1, as it we modeled a GLMM with a logit link function.

For the continuous case it is OK. We can say for a one-increase in logSB we will get an exp(1.326) increase risk of death. But this is OK as logSB take positive values.
So how can we say something like "for a one-unit increase in expit(value(spiders)) we will have a...". To me, it makes not much sense of saying for a one-unit increase in the probability of spiders, as it ranges from 0 to 1 only.
I mean, here spiders is not a dummy variable, right? We cannot say having spiders=Yes at time t increase the risk of death by exp(0.458)?
I am not sure of the interpretation. Any help would be much appreciated.
